# PeerJs (wrapper of webrtc) .send do not working

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I'm working on a P2P connection implementation using PeerJs and have created a PeerPlayer class to extend its functionalities. The main idea is to have just one super node and, upon receiving an event on this super node, broadcast to all nodes except the originating node.

I'm facing a challenge where I can only broadcast by opening new connections for each new send. For some reason, saving the connection and reusing it later isn't working. Has anyone encountered something similar or has suggestions on what might be happening?

I removed the code that isn't related to PeerJS. So, in the case I've written below, I tested by opening one tab (localhost) and another (localhost?invitation=xxxxxx). After that, I went to the first tab and executed in the dev tools console "peer.broadCast({event: 'playerMove', data:{}})", but the "client" (second node) didn't receive anything.

Here's the PeerPlayer class I extended from PeerJs:

```js
class PeerPlayer extends Peer {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id);
    this.peerCoonections = new Map();

    this.on("connection", (conn) => {
      console.log("Connection established with:", conn.peer);
      this.peerCoonections.set(conn.peer, conn);
      conn.on("data", (data) => {
        if (!data.event) return;
        this.emit(data.event, { conn, data });
      });
      conn.on("error", (err) => {
        console.error("Erro na conexão:", err);
      });
    });
  }

  broadCast(data, blockedList = []) {
    console.log("Broadcasting data:", data);
    this.peerCoonections.forEach((conn, peerId) => {
      console.log("Checking connection for peer:", peerId);
      if (!conn.open) {
        console.log("closed connection, returning");
        return;
      }
      if (blockedList.includes(conn.peer)) return;
      console.log("Sending data to peer:", peerId);
      conn.send(data);
    });
  }
}
```

And

```js
const peer = new PeerPlayer();
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const another_id = urlParams.get("invitation");
const peerIdelement = document.getElementById("peerId");
let me_is_host = false;

peer.on("open", (id) => {
  peerIdelement.innerText = id;

  if (another_id) {
    const conn = peer.connect(another_id);
    conn.on("open", () => {
      conn.send({
        event: "playerJoin",
        content: {
          id,
        },
      });
    });
  } else {
    me_is_host = true;
  }
});

peer.on("playerJoinResponse", (response) => {
  console.log(response);
});

peer.on("playerJoin", (playerJoin) => {
  const conn = playerJoin.conn;
  conn.send({
    event: "playerJoinResponse",
    content: {
      players: [],
    },
  });
});

peer.on("playerMove", (playerMove) => {
  const conn = playerMove.conn;
  const data = playerMove.data;

  if (me_is_host) {
    peer.broadCast(data, [conn.peer]);
  }
});
```